# Posso ter um único arquivo de rotas em angularjs e ter vários modulos?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho o interesse em separar minha app por modulo

```
app
controllers
views
diretivas
services
--modules
----principal
--------controllers
--------views
--------service
--------index.html
----cadastro
--------controllers
--------views
--------service
--------index.html
----financeiro
--------controllers
--------views
--------service
--------index.html
app.js
```

Sendo a primeira pasta controller e views que seria o login e o template do meu sistema
Porém todos os exemplos que encontro, cada modulo possui suas rotas

teria como apenas um arquivo manipular todas as rotas de todos os modulos?

Answer (score 1):

Rod,

o usuário deve estar caindo no index.html quando entra no se site, certo? Basta chamar o arquivo de rotas dentro dele, exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="routes.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</html>
```

**routes.js**

```
angularModule.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/principal', {
        templateUrl: 'principal/index.html',
        controller: 'PrincipalCtrl'
      }).
      when('/cadastro', {
        templateUrl: 'cadastro/index.html',
        controller: 'CadastroCtrl'
      }).
      when('/financeiro', {
        templateUrl: 'financeiro/index.html',
        controller: 'FinanceiroCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/404'
      });
  }])
```

Claro que você vai ter que adaptar essas rotas pra sua necessidade, foi só um exemplo. Mas enfim, todas as rotas em um único arquivo, que vai chamando os respectivos controllers e seus templates.

Comment: fala rafael, então cara, dessa forma deixa de ser modular, que é como eu fiz minha app. Quanto a rotas, por ser uma app corporativa, não quero que tenha o registro de rotas tudo em um único arquivo, além de que, após o login, as rotas devem ser criadas conforme sua permissão, vindo da Api, mas obrigado por responder

Comment: Rod, entendi o lance modular, mas confesso que não entendi perfeitamente o que você precisa. Entendi que as rotas precisam estar em seus respectivos módulos, mas você quer também criar rotas dinamicamente após o login? E, que tipo de manipulação é essa que você precisa em um único arquivo?

Comment: Rafael, então, no login, não quero expor todas as minhas rotas, então iria redirecionar para um modulo, e após o login criar essa rotas dinamicamente, que viria do retorno da API

Comment: Mas, por que estas rotas não podem estar criadas antes do login? Se o usuário acessar uma url que não está permitida por algum motivo, você redireciona ele. Cria um UserService pra isso. Imagino que cada url que ele acessar, você precisará acessar a API pra pegar os dados dele, certo? Sua API vai retornar dizendo que o usuário não está logado? Se sim, esse UserService vai fazer esse controle de acesso. Ficou confuso?

Comment: O problema, que por ser uma app corporativa, logo na tela de login haverá todas as rotas, então, qualquer um poderá ver todos os meus módulos de trabalho, e até mesmo ideia do que se trata a minha app, o qual quem deve saber das novidades e etc é apenas o meu cliente final.

Todo controlle de acesso é feito via api sim, e é redirecionado se não possui acesso

Comment: Só me explica essa parte: "logo na tela de login haverá todas as rotas". Haverá como exatamente?

Comment: rafael, se todas as rotas ficarão no arquivo app.js, basta acessar o source code da página e terá todas as rotas

Comment: Ok, entendi. To pensando numa solução.